# How to create array of different types that all conforms Equatable protocol?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm following a SwiftUI course, and I want to animate my view with multiple values. In the tutorial, the `animation` modifier is used without the value parameter but XCode says it's deprecated. `animation` modifier requires a `value` now.

My goal is to add multiple values to that animation, I think of Array for it. I have two boolean values, `show` and `showCard` and one `CGSize`.

I cast this array with `as [Any]` because Array of two boolean and 1 CGSize gives this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'CGSize' to expected element type 'Bool'
```

When I use `as [Any]`, I can't conform `Equatable`.

```
Protocol 'Any' as a type cannot conform to 'Equatable'
```

And then I've tried like this:

```
as [Any : Equatable]
```

and error is:

```
Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'
```

I can try lot of things but I want to understand:

1. How to give multiple values for 1 animation?

or

1. How to make an Array with different types, which all conforms to a protocol?

Code of my view:

```
    BackCardView()
        .frame(width: 340, height: 220)
        .background(Color(show ? "card4" : "card3"))
        .cornerRadius(20.0)
        .shadow(radius: 20)
        .offset(x: 0, y: show ? -200 : -20)
        .offset(x: viewState.width, y: viewState.height)
        .offset(y: showCard ? -140 : 0)
        .scaleEffect(showCard ? 1 : 0.95)
        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: (show ? 0: 5)))
        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees:  showCard ? -5 : 0))
        .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: showCard ? 5 : 0), axis: (x: 10.0, y: 0, z: 0))
        .blendMode(.hardLight)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3), value: [show, showCard, viewState])
```

Comment: You asked for How to give multiple values for 1 animation? not good idea! do all in deferent animations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply various animations separately, e.g.

```
.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3), value: show)
.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3), value: showCard)
.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3), value: viewState)
```

That is: each modifier applies the same animation to the view, but on different conditions.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is that you the array that you need to transmit should be conform to equatable :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable

When your array contains Bool and CGSize , swift can't perform equality between a Bool and CGSize. And In this context it doesn't make sens to make them equatable.

To realise what you want to do you can simply add 2 animation :

```
.animation(.default, value: [show, showCard])
.animation(.default, value: viewState)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, after @Kiril S. answer, I already went with your answer. Used array for bools, and separate .animation for viewState

Comment: Yes kiril was faster than me ! juste see his answer when posted mine

Comment: @JoakimDanielson not necessarily, I think grouping same types is also inspiring

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sorry to disagree , but I thinks the other answer is not complete, it doesn't explain why the CGSize can't be added to the array, and also it make think that Array can't be use as value. That why I think this answer is also pertinent. Maybe we should merge the answers ?